# How to understand Process.Threads.Count results? What this variable display?

Tags: .net, multithreading

Lets write simple console application (debug mode):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        IList<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        Console.WriteLine(p.Threads.Count);
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(Test);
            Console.WriteLine("Before start: {0}", p.Threads.Count);
            t.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("After start: {0}", p.Threads.Count);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
```

What do you think you will see in results?

**[Q1] Why p.Threads.Count differ from Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`Process.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.refresh.aspx) before you fetch the `Threads` property each time, to avoid seeing the results of caching.

Do that and you'll see the results you expect.