# Current process without threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, mono

I tried to set the processor affinity for threads in Unity as it was discussed here: [Set Thread Processor Affinity in Microsoft .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328751/set-thread-processor-affinity-in-microsoft-net)

However, the following method prints "Process Thread Count = 0" all the time. Creating and starting manual threads didn't change the result:

```
void Start()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    Debug.Log("Process Thread Count = " + process.Threads.Count);
}
```

So there are no threads I could set the affinity for. Is there something I am doing wrong? I'm using Unity 4.5.1f3 which is based on Mono 2.0.50727.1433!

Comment: Affinity it's how many cores threads will use. if you have affinity equal to 2 and you have 4 threads, then just of them will use CPU at one moment, and they will be switched. And thread number doesn't depend on affinity. Affinity just restricts active thread count, but total count can be much bigger than Affinity number

Comment: @Sergey: I don't quite understand what you've written. As far as I know affinity is about which cores a thread is allowed to be run on. However, that doesn't even affect my question. Why are there no threads in the current process? Shouldn't there be at least one?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But count of thread can be much bigger than count of cores. So `process.Threads.Count` doesn't depend on affinity. And Yes, `Thread.Count` shouldn't be equal to 0. In .Net application there will be at least 2-3 threads depending on application type. On is main thread, and another one is for GC. Maybe it's some Mono issue? Or it's permission issue?

Comment: @Sergey: I know that the amount of threads can be bigger (and usually is bigger) than the amount of cores and that the thread count doesn't depend on affinity but I need to access all threads of the current process to find the ProcessThread corresponding to the current managed thread I want to set the affinity for. Thank you for the hint about it being a Mono or permission issue, though.

Comment: Have you tried `process.Refresh()` as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216841/how-to-understand-process-threads-count-results-what-this-variable-display)?

Comment: @maZZZu: Thanks for the hint. I've tried it now but sadly it didn't change anything.

Comment: Mono 2.0 is ancient, maybe it didn't work back then. It does work for me using 3.10. I understand you might not be able to upgrade due to unity, that's unfortunate.

Comment: @Jester: I was really afraid of such an answer but I also start to believe that this is the reason. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it's a bug! I've created a bug report some days ago and today I got the following answer:

*"[...] We have fixed this and [the] problem will not appear in the next major version. [...]"*

Now I'm curious what the next major version will be.